# Squeal on start up and turning left

Tags: ford, noise, bronco

I have an 87 Ford Bronco with a 5.0. There is a loud squeal on start up and when turning left. Not a power steering pump squeal. Much louder. And it's a ticking squeal. Not a constant squeal. The two times the squeal has continued after start up I immediately put it into drive after starting it. I've done a torque converter test, removed the belt and started it. Spin the pulleys, the smog pump pulley has a bit of wobble to it but since the squeal was still there after the belt was removed I've ruled it out as the culprit. It's much louder underneath the vehicle than it is on the top end. I can't pinpoint the problem - any hints or tips? I'm perplexed by the turning left as it doesn't do it when turning right.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Is there any hesitation in starting (does it seem to turn over slow at first)? How is the oil pressure?  I'm wondering about the health of the bottom end of the engine, but wondering how the left hand turn would figure into it ... doesn't make sense.

Comment: You say it's not the power steering - how did you eliminate this? Have you removed the power steering belt and started the engine and turned the steering wheel?

Comment: pull and check the distributor ....chances its wore out..harmonics make it sound like its coming from the bottom from the oil pump rod and oil pump